# Explicit funtion template instantiation not working

Tags: c++, explicit-instantiation

I have a template function which I would like to hide from the user , therefore I declare the interface in the header file, the implementation with the explicit instantiation in a cpp file:

```
  // lib.hpp file
   template<typename CT>
   std::unique_ptr<CT> fun( int a, int b);


  // lib.cpp file 
   #include "lib.hpp"
   #include "class_a.hpp"
   template<typename CT>
   std::unique_ptr<CT> fun(int a, int b) { return std::make_unique<CT>(a,b) ; };

   std::unique_ptr<class_a> fun(int a, int b);


   // user file cpp 
    #include "lib.hpp"
    auto test_ = fun(a,b); // this is returns an error
```

The error from the user file says "no matching function for call to..."

After the comments it seems like I must specify the template type like: `fun<class_a>(a,b);`
My motivation is namely to avoid exposing `class_a` to the user, or at least its header file. How do you work around this.

Comment: You need to specify what `CT` is when you call `fun`, i.e `fun<class_a>(a, b)`

Comment: why is the compiler not able to figure that out. There is only one possible way for the `fun`

Comment: Because that's how templates work.  It doesn't matter that you've stamp out an explicit specialization.  The compiler is going to try and do template argument deduction so it can check which specialization to use, and since it can't determine the template parameter, it cant determine the specialization.

Comment: Also, that's not a specialisation you produced, but an overload.

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay thanks. That seems to act differently from explicit template instantiation for classes

Answer (score 0):

Think of templates almost as if the compiler is just doing string substitution. What is going to get substituted needs to be known at the point you're using it.

It's not that you're creating a method called `foo`. You're creating a template, and you get a distinct `foo` for each type of parameter that matches. That could be 10 or 100 actual methods, each taking a different type, and isn't remarkably different that if you actually just defined 100 different `foo` methods using operator overloading.

In other words, for templates that will be used by your users, it has to be in the include file.

You could hide details if you can do a lot of it in private methods, but that's tricky design.